# Create polylines using vue2-google-maps

Tags: google-maps, vuejs2

I used vue2-google-maps and set the path from one country to another but I want to have a line where i can traced it. A dashed line to be specific. Here's my code

```
<gmap-map
:center="center"
:zoom="7"
style="width: 500px; height: 300px">
<gmap-marker
  v-for="m in markers"
  :position="m.position"
  :clickable="true"
  :draggable="true"
  @click="center=m.position"
></gmap-marker>
```

```
export default {
data () {
  return {
    center: {lat: 10.0, lng: 10.0},
    markers: [{
      position: {lat: 14.5995, lng: 120.9842},
      position: {lat: 14.2440, lng: 120.4278},
      position: {lat: 16.2325, lng: 119.3264}
    }, {
      position: {lat: 22.3964, lng: 114.1095}
    }]
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to do something like this:

```
      <gmap-map v-bind:center="center" v-bind:zoom="12" style="width: 800px; height:500px" >
        <gmap-polyline v-bind:path.sync="path" v-bind:options="{ strokeColor:'#008000'}">
         </gmap-polyline>
      </gmap-map


export default {
    data () {
      return { 
        center: {lat: 55.915655, lng: -4.744502},
          path: [
            {lat: 55.9352001, lng: -4.7766924 },
            {lat: 55.9358131, lng: -4.7770143 },
            {lat: 55.9361256, lng: -4.7767353 },
            {lat: 55.9366784, lng: -4.7739458 }
]
            }
        }
      }
```